# Fit student t to incomplete distribution

Tags: r, distribution

Thanks to a closed form formula (I work on risk neutral density, with this king of formula: [RND formula](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/wbs/subjects/finance/research/wpaperseries/1998/98-95.pdf), page 8), I have an incomplete distribution of this type:

[image: RND estimate]

My idea would be to fit this density with a student-t.

I already tried the [MASS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/MASS.pdf) and [fitdistrplus](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/fitdistrplus.pdf) packages but just can't find how to perform my task. Everything I can do for now is to get the fitted parameters (m=1702.041, s=6.608536, df=15.18036), but from here I don't know how to get my fitted values for my distribution.

A sample of code:

```
temp = matrix(nrow=1000, ncol=3)
colnames(temp) = c("strikes", "first_density", "mulitply_first_density")
temp = as.data.frame(temp)

# we generate fake data
temp$strikes = seq(1000,2000,length=1000)
temp$first_density = runif(1000,max=0.006, min=1e-10)

# we multiply our first density to generate our sample
temp$mulitply_first_density = temp$first_density*1000000

# we generate our sample
vec = vector()
for (i in 1:nrow(temp))
{
    vec = c(vec, rep(temp$strike[i], temp$mulitply_first_density[i]))
}

# we laod our library
library("MASS")

# we fir our parameters
fitted_parameters = fitdistr(vec, "t")
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Are you asking how to calculate the density values of a t-distribution from these parameters?

Comment: My question was not clear, my apologies. Indeed this is the task I would like to perform

Comment: Please show the code you have used for deriving these parameters.

Comment: As asked I uploaded some code in the initial question

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the t-density function using the location and scale parameters is given in the examples of the documentation as `mydt`.

```
#simulated data
set.seed(42)
x <- rt(1e4, 7, 10)
plot(density(x))

library(MASS)
fitted_parameters = fitdistr(x, "t", start = list(df = 10, m = 10, s = 5))
#      df             m             s     
#  3.81901649   10.56816146    2.66905346 
#( 0.15295551) ( 0.03448627) ( 0.03361758)

mydt <- function(x, m, s, df) dt((x-m)/s, df)/s
curve(do.call(mydt, c(list(x), as.list(fitted_parameters$estimate))), add = TRUE, col = "red")
legend("topright", legend = c("kernel density estimate", "fitted t distribution"), 
       col = c("black", "red"), lty = 1)
```

[image: resulting plot]